# Animating the origin point location. Is it possible?

Tags: animation, edit-mode

I want to animate the rotation of a plane (I need to move it from position 1 to position 2, using 2 turns and rotating by Z axis) as in the picture below. However to do so, I need the origin point to move from the left to the right side of a plane. Is it possible to keyfame the origin point location?
[image]

Comment: This should be possible using Shape Keys.