# how do I change the point of rotation

Tags: animation

For example, if I were to simplify the following animation to just 2 cubes and have one of them not move and have the other one "walk" around the static cube (4 steps to make the complete circuit).  I tried moving the object's origin and that didn't work and I also tried moving the 3d cursor and that didn't work either.

http://cmdrkitten.tumblr.com/post/167838417054

Comment: I had similar problem some time ago (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19258/animating-the-origin-point-location-is-it-possible). Here's a link that may help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/802/how-can-i-change-the-centre-of-rotation-of-objects-during-an-animation

Comment: [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drw6n.gif) of also [loosely related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69731/rotate-a-cube-on-a-plane-using-drivers/69747#69747).

Comment: Also related: [pivot constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7184/30849).